# How to get the path name of an image inside the properties.resources in Microsoft .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, image, properties, resources

this is my first question in stack overflow (Ye hey)!

So I am using Itext 7 to create PDF files in my program. When creating a PDF, the document inside has an image logo. It work when I run the program in debug mode using this path name:

```
string imageFile = "../../Resources/smIcon(Transparent).png";
ImageData imagedata = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageFile);
Image image = new Image(imagedata).SetHeight(100).SetWidth(200);
document.Add(image);
```

However, publishing the project and running the application does not let me create the PDF due to the Path name... I tried publishing without the logo by removing the code above and it works to create a PDF document, which I suspect the issue is the path name.

Would be great to know if you guys have a solution for this! Thank you.

Comment: You need to either embed the image in the resources of the program and get it from there or copy it somewhere in your programs directory when installing and use the path to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to work on it with a help of a good friend.

```
ImageData imagedata = ImageDataFactory.Create(Properties.Resources.smIcon_Transparent_, null);
Image image = new Image(imagedata).SetHeight(100).SetWidth(200);
```

So basically with this way, I don't need to get the actual path name of the file but instead get the one that is in the **properties.resource**, where publishing the project does not need to change the path.